# I ran tar command with the -v switch, but got no output, why?

Tags: tar

After running:

```
tar -xvf directory.tar
```

I don't get any error but I can't see the output.

Does anyone can help me?

Comment: Have you looked for it? Use the file browser or run `ls`.

Comment: locate _directory_ and no results

Comment: `v` should force tar to print all files processed. Check to make sure there is something in the tarball with `tar -tf directory.tar`

Answer (score 2):

> The tar file was corrupt.

OP answered itself.

Answer (score 0):

look for hidden files through 
ls -a

I looked up some material on repairing tar and came across this http://riaschissl.bestsolution.at/2014/03/repost-how-to-repair-corrupt-tar-archives/

Basically I think you need to open tar file in a hex editor and experiment with which sections are good.